# Search api shows dialog on mac

Tags: javascript, macos, ms-word, office365, add-in

when searching the text in word document on mac it shows the dialog that displays the message "word has reached the end of document do you want to continue searching at the begining"? how to prevent the word from prompting this dialog.
I have used the context.document.body.search method in javascript.
.

Comment: It's not clear from your question which programming language you're using. I usually don't' associate "add-ins" with Mac-Word, only with WinWord... Is this VBA or what?

Answer (score 0):

Word's `Find` object has a `Wrap` property which accepts one of the three `WdFindWrap` enumeration members `wdFindAsk`, `wdFindStop` or `wdFindContinue`.

The behavior you're seeing comes from the first of these, which is the UI default.

The last of the three will continue the search from the beginning of the document without asking - this is dangerous because it could lead to an non-ending loop.

When automating Word `wdFindStop` is almost always the preferred setting: the Find will stop at the end of the specified Range, whether something was found, or not.

So set `Find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop` in your code to prevent the prompt and to make sure the code doesn't enter an endless loop.